# Service fabric deploy deprecated files from previous deployment

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When redeploying an application on service fabric (using `Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication`), why do I always see the files from previous deployment ? Some file of my application seems not deleted properly or cached somewhere.

For example

- `APPversionA` includes `fileA`
- `APPversionB` includes `fileB`

Result in target _VM "SF/_App" data directory:

- first deployment `APPversionA`: I got `AppXX/MyService/Code/fileA` : OK
- then when I deploy `APPversionB` that replace `APPversionA`:

  - I got `AppYY/MyService/Code/fileA`
  - and `AppYY/MyService/Code/fileB`
  - **Failed**: expected to have fileB only !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `ApplicationManifest.xml` of my application I had "1.8-SNAPSHOT" as `ApplicationTypeVersion` attribute value.

So I encounter the issue when updating and redeploying this SNAPSHOT version multiples times.

Seems like in this usecase - as `ApplicationTypeVersion` is unchanged - SF overrides or append the deployment bundle content of the previous deployment instead of recreating a new one from scratch (for me it's an issue).

To fix it, I add build timestamp to `ApplicationTypeVersion` value (ex. `1.8-SNAPSHOT-20160128_1113`) . This case, there is no more ServiceFabric cache effect. The version and deployment content is updated for each deployment.